# does javascript code need to start with "<!-- "?

Tags: javascript, html

I am newbie.

many of javascript code  start with  `<!--`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
```

and finish with  `//-->`

```
//-->
    </script>
```

I think the reason is for compatibility.
But I cannot find the clue in any books.

even I cannot find anything  with google.

Comment: Sorry about my horrible English.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. This is a holdover from the days when Netscape 2 was common.

It isn't needed with any browser that can function on the web today, and it is positively harmful in XHTML.

I wrote [a longer explanation](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/) last year.

Answer (score 1):

No, Javascript can run perfectly fine without them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was to hide JavaScript from any browser that doesn't know how to handle it. Those browsers used to display the code to the user. Hence, a way to hide code from those browsers was introduced. As there aren't any browsers around that don't know about JavaScript nowadays, it's mainly a remainder from the good ol' days :)