# Clear all the open div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script that open's div's by doing an onclick="toogle_visibility(id)

event but how do i do when i want to close the div that is open and open

the new div ?

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navBar">
<a href="#social" onclick="toggle_visibility('Social')">Social</a>
<a href="#social" onclick="toggle_visibility('Foljer')">F&ouml;ljer</a>
<a href="#social" onclick="toggle_visibility('Bokmarken')">Bokm&auml;rken</a>
</div>
<div id="Social">
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/Liam_Rab3">@Liam_Rab3 - TWITTER</a><br>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/Liam_Rab3">@Liam_Rab3 - INSTAGRAM</a><br>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/LiamRab3">@LiamRab3- FACEBOOK</a><br>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/howmuchtimedr">@Liam_Rab3 - YOUTUBE</a><br>
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/Liam_Rab3">@Liam_Rab3 - FLICKR</a><br>
<a href="http://www.thenotallowedguy.tk">@Liam_Rab3 - TUMBLR</a><br>
</div>
<div id="Foljer">
<a href="http://www.instagram.com/sebbestakset">Sebbe Stakset (Kartellen)</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a:link {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
}
a:hover {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:100%;
}
a:visited {
text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #0066BB;
color:white;
}
#social {
display:none;
}
#Foljer {
display:none;
}
```

**DISCLAIMER!**

These links in the #social and #bokmarken links is'nt for commercial purpose.

Comment: [Stop putting JavaScript in HTML comments.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944764/wrapping-javascript-in)

Comment: Do you only want to allow one of the selected divs ['Social', 'Foljer', 'Bokmarken'] to be opend at once, or can multiple menus be opened?

Comment: We say i click on 'Foljer' but then i want to open 'Social' so the 'Foljer' div closes and the 'Social' div opens

Comment: possible duplicate of [toggle show/hide div with button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery [Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here !!!
</div>
<a href="#social" >Social</a>

$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#social" ).toggle(); //With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements:
});
```

First choose the control you are willing to hide/show, then use that control's id as follows:

```
$('#<id-of-that-control>').toggle();
```

Now you can call that in the onclick event handler of a button or div as you wish.

How it might appear for you is:

**JS**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
     $('#' + id).toggle();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navBar">
<a href="#social" onclick="toggle_visibility('Social')">Social</a>
<a href="#social" onclick="toggle_visibility('Foljer')">F&ouml;ljer</a>
<a href="#social" onclick="toggle_visibility('Bokmarken')">Bokm&auml;rken</a>
</div>
```

**Update**:
As pointed out by Brodie, seemingly you might always look into the solution provided by Niet the Dark Absol. As he provides you a pure JS implementation. My solution will give you insight of using a library like JQuery and it's API of toggle. Jquery provides a wide range of built-in functionality that helps you to do things quickly. What my piece of code provides you is usage of an api i.e. toggle, which when used will be same as the hide and show behavior.

Comment: Can i change the $( "#book" ).toggle( "slow", function() { with
$( "id" ).toggle( "slow", function() { or something like that ?

Comment: Yeah, or just right one function and bind it to the element with $(this).click(function()

Comment: So... basically you're taking perfectly functional JavaScript, bloating it up like no tomorrow with jQuery, and still not actually doing what OP wants...?

Comment: I swear no one can actually write pure JS anymore.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol firstyl, there is a tag of JQuery and also, if everything we provide the complete code, then we still dont ensure that the user will learn on his own anything. He would start using the same logic we provide. So the link of toggle is important for him to understand by reading the usage.

Comment: @LearningByCoding There's a [pure JS implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528122/1095883) there.

Comment: @Brodie Okay fare enough, so let me say, yet the answer selected as jquery toggle. I still do not get it, the tag says jquery also, whats wrong for that? Why downvote?

Comment: @LearningByCoding It's clear the OP isn't knowledgeable of the differences between pure Javascript and a library like jQuery based on his mislabelling of the code snippet (it contained zero jQuery). I downvoted the OP as it's a duplicate. I haven't upvoted your own answer as I agree with above: his question and level of presumed understanding can be cleared up with pure JS along with a helpful explanation of when it's appropriate to include such a library.

Comment: @Brodie Fare enough. Have updated the answer so that he can choose the knowledge of pure JS.

Comment: `toggle` isn't even the appropriate function, because OP wants to close whichever one is open...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to close all DIVs, and toggle the current one.

Try this:

```
var ids = ['Social','Foljer','Bokmarken'];
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var l = ids.length, i, e;
   for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
       e = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
       if( id != ids[i])
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```